# SQL multiple if statements, same result set, different argument

Tags: sql, function, dry

I am writing a stored proc that calculates a WHOLE bunch of different things, but I have a bit in it, that is repeated about 9 times.

eg:

```
if @argA = 1 (true)
select Count(samples) from dbo.X where type = @argAType

if @argB = 1 (true)
select Count(samples) from dbo.X where type = @argBType

if @argC = 1
select Count(samples) from dbo.X where type = @argCType
```

and so on...

how can I write a function (or something similar) that I can pass in a bit (true or false), and other argument, and only return the result set if true???

Comment: What do you want it to return when the bits are "false"?

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're looking for? This is the best I can deduce based on the question as it's currently posted.

```
SELECT COUNT(samples)
FROM dbo.X
WHERE
    (type=@argAType AND @argA=1)
    OR
    (type=@argBType AND @argB=1)
    OR
    (type=@argCType AND @argC=1)
```

---

In function form, I think this is right:

```
CREATE FUNCTION GetCount(@n AS BIGINT) RETURNS BIGINT
AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @count BIGINT

  SELECT @count = COUNT(samples)
    FROM dbo.X
    WHERE
        (type=@argAType AND @argA=1)
        OR
        (type=@argBType AND @argB=1)
        OR
        (type=@argCType AND @argC=1)

  RETURN @count
END
```